# VBA Excel page break at change in cell to every worksheet in the workbook

Tags: excel, page-break, vba

I have some code to add a page break at a change in cell contents, however I am unable to get it to run for more than the active sheet. I have about 80 sheets I need to run this on and need it to run at the same time. I have tried running it on ThisWorkbook, but it doesn't work. It will work great on a sheet by sheet basis, but not on the entire workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Set_PageBreaks()

    Dim lastrow As Long, c As Range

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
        If c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> c.Value And c.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of a sloppy solution (because you shouldn't really use `activate`), but this should work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Set_PageBreaks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws_count As Long, i as long, lastrow As Long, c As Range
ws_count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 to ws_count

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Activate

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
        If c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> c.Value And c.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            c.Offset(1, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    Next c

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @K.Davis And why would a sheet be deleted?

Comment: @K.Davis And that is completely irrelevant to this macro. `ws_count` is dynamically created each time - That's exactly why we use `ws_count` here instead of a static number like `80`.

Comment: @K.Davis I think you're misreading the effect of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Activate` - **Sheet name** is irrelevant - that is iterating through the sheets, in order, that exist in the workbook.

Comment: If I had 5 sheets, named "Tim", "Bob", "Mary", "Michael", and "Joe", `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name` would return "Mary".

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would handle your issue:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Set_PageBreaks()

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, C As Range, lastrow As Long

    Call SpeedUpCode(True)

    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each C In Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
            If C.Offset(1, 0).Value <> C.Value And C.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
                C.Offset(1, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
            End If
        Next C
    Next Sheet

    Call SpeedUpCode(False)

End Sub

Sub SpeedUpCode(ByVal Value As Boolean)
    With Application
        If Value = True Then
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        ElseIf Value = False Then
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```